# Who is being attacked in ibn Kathir's tafsir for Sura 100?

Tags: quran, tafseer, prophet-muhammad

Here's the excerpt from the tafsir that I'm asking about:

> (And scouring to the raid at dawn.) meaning, the raid that is carried
>   out in the early morning time. This is just as the Messenger of Allah
>   used to perform raids in the early morning. He would wait to see if he
>   heard the Adhan (call to prayer) from the people. If he heard it he
>   would leave them alone, and if he didn't hear it he would attack. Then
>   Allah says,

[Tafsir ibn Kathir, Sura 100](http://www.alim.org/library/quran/AlQuran-tafsir/TIK/100/1)

It sounds like Muhammad is attacking Muslims. That doesn't make any sense. What does it mean? Whom is Muhammad attacking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ibn Kathir is alluding to the narration about surprise attacks carried out by the Prophet ﷺ in enemy territory, as related for example [here](http://sunnah.com/muslim/4/11) and [here](http://sunnah.com/bukhari/10/8).

The Prophet would observe whether the [adhan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adhan) for Fajr was called or not. If it was called  he would not attack as there were Muslims among the inhabitants.

Comment: Thanks, I was confused. I thought all the Muslims lived in Medina with the rest of the Ummah.